# How to check collisions between rotated rectangle and a straight line?

Tags: collision-detection

How do I detect collisions between a rotated rectangle and a straight line?

[image]

Comment: http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/line-point.php you can navigate through examples at the top. Might be useful to start simpler and work your way upwards. Best wishes

Comment: How are each of these shapes specified in your internal representation? If the rectangle is a rotation, center position, width and height, then you can apply the inverse of these parameters to map it to an axis-aligned unit square centered at the origin, and your line to a corresponding line in that space. Now you've reduced the problem to a much simpler one with fewer variables (only the line's parameters remain)